# How string concat method works

Tags: java, string, concatenation

I know String in Java is immutable. Consider:

```
String s = "Java";
s = s.concat(" is simple");
System.out.println(s); //prints Java is simple
```

Here the value of String s is changed? Can someone explain me, how String concat actually works?

Comment: Don't confuse variables, reference values, and objects. This has nothing to do with immutability.

Answer (score 0):

`s.concat(" is simple")` returns a new string and `s = s.concat(" is simple")` assigns this new string to variable `s`.